# R: conditionally delete rows on basis of last column values in R

Tags: r

I have a two excel files contain data 
The first excel file is like:
[frequency.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrsNS.png)

and second excel file contains data:
interval.xlsx

```
intervalStart   intervalEnd
1                 10
11                20
31                40
51                70
```

Now i want to write a R code which read first row from interval.xlsx file and compare in first file (frequency.xlsx) with each value in  last column (that is col 8) value and delete entire row if value is between intervalStart and intervalEnd.

**For ex.**
read first row of interval.xlsx i.e **1 and 10** 
now check each value in last column of frequency.xlsx if value is between **1 and 10** delete entire row otherwise continue.
again read second  row of interval.xlsx and continue

so Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Bioconductor package IRanges has many functions to work with ranges:

```
require(IRanges)
a<-data.frame(start=c(1,11,31,51),
           end=c(10,20,40,70))
aranges <- IRanges(a$start,a$end)

b <- data.frame(Col1=sample(LETTERS,75, replace=T),
                Col2 = 1:75)
branges <- IRanges(b$Col2, b$Col2)

b[!overlapsAny(branges,aranges),]
# Col1 Col2
# 21    R   21
# 22    G   22
# 23    I   23
# 24    H   24
# 25    G   25
# 26    I   26
# 27    V   27
# 28    T   28
# 29    Z   29
# 30    E   30
# 41    H   41
# 42    J   42
# 43    A   43
# 44    N   44
# 45    H   45
# 46    P   46
# 47    T   47
# 48    L   48
# 49    P   49
# 50    U   50
# 71    U   71
# 72    B   72
# 73    K   73
# 74    R   74
# 75    Y   75
```

Comment: Please be more specific